# How to render a foreignObject SVG encoded with Base64 on browser

Tags: html, svg, encoding, base64, foreignobject

I have written the SVG code below. I want to encode it with Base64 and display it with `data:image/svg+xml;base64,BASE64ENCODINGHERE`. The issue is probably with `foreignobject` but I cannot see the text on the image. How can I solve this problem?

For this case the Base64 encoding is:

```
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
```

So, the link becomes:

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,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
```

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 500 250">
  <style>
    div {
      font: 14px serif;
      height: 200px;
      width: 480px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .base {
      font-family: serif;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  </style>
  <rect x="0" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" width="500" height="250" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:0.1;stroke-opacity:0.9" />
  <foreignobject x="8" y="8" width="490" height="240">
    <text x="10" y="160" class="base">Category:xaxaxa</text>
    <div>hebele hubele bum bam bum</div>
  </foreignobject>
</svg>
```

Expected output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93xwB.png)

Result I got:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZH6l.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's foreignObject with a capital O. SVG is case sensitive except when it's embedded in HTML.
2. You need to specify that the div lives in the XHTML namespace
3. There's no such thing as a text element in HTML so if you want to keep that, move it from the foreignObject contents. I've just removed it. That gives us this...

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 500 250">
  <style>
div {
  font: 14px serif;
  height: 200px;
  width: 480px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.base {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
  </style>
  <rect x="0" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" width="500" height="250" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:0.1;stroke-opacity:0.9" />
  <foreignObject x="8" y="8" width="490" height="240">
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">hebele hubele bum bam bum</div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

and if you base64 encode that you get

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,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
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Robert, both for the solution and your fast response! That solved my issue.